# Problem evaluating $C^{-1}M^\dagger C$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

How can I show the following?

$$\overline{\psi_L}M^\dagger (\psi_L)^c=\overline{\psi_L}CM^\dagger\overline{\psi_L}^T$$

where $\psi^c=C\overline{\psi}^T$ and $C=i\gamma^2\gamma^0=-C^T=-C^\dagger=-C^{-1}$. In particular, what is $C^{-1}M^\dagger C$? I'm stuck at this point. If I can show, $$C^{-1}M^\dagger C=M^\dagger$$, the job is done.

EDIT: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0001264

see equation 24 of this review

Comment: is $M$ a matrix? if so, in what space? in what space is $C$ a matrix? won't their commutation be trivial? or did i miss something?

Comment: @innisfree, you are right. $M$ is a matrix on flavor space while $C$ only acts on the spinors.

Comment: @JeffDror yes that is exactly what I was implying :)

Comment: So what is the resolution? It is true that M is a matrix on flavor space while C only acts on the spinors, but $\psi_L$ is a vector in the flavor space (in this case), then how do you define $\psi_L^c$?

Comment: Are you ultimately trying to show that $M$ must be symmetric?

Comment: @innisfree - why do you say that? I'm trying to show, $\overline{\psi_L}M^\dagger (\psi_L)^c=\overline{\psi_L}CM^\dagger\overline{\psi_L}^T$. I have attached the review as well. This is what people use in writing the Majorana mass term for a species of n-neutrinos. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $ C $ and $ M $ are matrices in different spaces. Explicitly showing the flavor space matrices, in the lepton sector perhaps, we have,
\begin{align} 
\overline{\psi} _L M ^\dagger \left( \psi _L \right) ^c & = \overline{\psi} _L M ^\dagger C\bar{ \psi _L} ^T   \\ 
& = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}\overline{ \psi _{e, L} } & \overline{ \psi _{ \mu , L } }  & \overline{ \psi _{ \tau , L}}\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
M _{1,1} & M _{1,2} & M _{1,3} \\  
M _{2,1} & M _{2,2} & M _{2,3} \\  
M _{3,1} & M _{3,2} &   M _{3,3}
\end{array} \right) ^\dagger\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
C & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & C & 0 \\  
0 & 0 & C  
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 
\gamma _0 \overline{  \psi _{e, L} }^T   \\  
\gamma _0 \overline{ \psi _{\mu ,L} } ^T   \\ 
\gamma _0 \overline{ \psi _{\tau, L} } ^T  
\end{array} \right) 
\end{align}

Comment: The Dirac mass term is written as $-\mathcal{L}_D=\bar\nu_R m_D\nu_L + \bar\nu_L m_D^\dagger \nu_R$. How can I get the second term by taking the hermitian conjugate of the first term? In case of single fermionic species $m_D$ is number. Right? And the proof is trivial. What about the proof when we have n-fermionic species.

Comment: Its also trivial in the case of $n$ species because $\gamma_0$ commutes with $m_D$ (they act on different spaces)